# MongoDB C#: Update.pullAll not removing items

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'am currently playing around with MongoDB using its C# driver, trying each method in the [API](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.0/html/5ae970ba-44a1-a0c7-2b79-6ddb7bc99109.htm) *(which would be leagues better if they provided some examples)* one by one.

And currently I'm on the `Update.PullAll()` method.

I'm using this POCO object for my tests:

```
public class Person 
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
}

public class Skill 
{
    public Object Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If populated, translates into this json object:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb3"),
   "Firstname" : "John",
   "Lastname" : "Doe",
   "Skills" : [
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecaf"),
          "Name" : "C#.NET"
       },
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb0"),
          "Name" : "ASP.NET"
       },
       {
          "_id" : ObjectId("4f979621682dbc1a8cefecb1"),
          "Name" : "SQL Server"
       }
   ]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to remove the elements from the skills collection.

Here is my code:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var db =  server.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Person>("person");

// Retrieve the data above from  mongoDB
var _person = collection.AsQueryable()
                        .Select(p => p).Single();

// Query to reference "John Doe"
var query = Query.EQ("_id",new ObjectId(_person.Id.ToString()));

// Collection of "John Doe's" skill ids
var objIds = _person.Skills
                    .Select(p => new ObjectId(p.Id.ToString()));

// Parse the skill ids to a BsonArray
var bsonArray = BsonArray.Create(objIds);

var update = Update.PullAll("Skills" , bsonArray);

// Call the Update command
collection.Update( query, update );
```

Which, does nothing; it leaves my json object intact.

Can anyone help me point out where did I go wrong in my code?
Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `$pullAll` to work, you have to match the whole object exactly, and cannot use just one field (even if it is called _id).

So you'd have to include the name as well in the update command (and the fields need to be in the same order, too).

The command you really want to use is `$pull`, which does what you need here, i.e. matching filtering criteria:

> In addition to matching an exact value you can also use expressions ([$pull is special in this way](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24pull)).

Even though it is called "pull without all", it does pull *all matched elements*, not just one. The "all" just means that you have one filter (whereas pullAll has multiple elements to match).

Comment: When I saw `PullAll()` I assumed it would function the same way as `InsertBatch()`, so that's where I went wrong. Thanks! this helped a lot.