# MongoDB pullAll objects with multiple arguments

Tags: mongodb, pull, mongodb-query

I just want to remove several Objects in from my array in mongoDB using pullAll

```
db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId(".....")}, { $pullAll : { 'notifications' : [{'type' : type}, {'id': id}]} })
```

Why is this not working? What is the correct syntax?

Update:

the document is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("......"),
    "notifications" : [ { "type" : "aaa",
                          "id" : "123" },
                        { "type" : "bbb",
                          "id" : "123" },
                        { "type" : "ccc",
                          "id" : "234" }]
}
```

Comment: What's the structure of your document ?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310837/mongodb-c-update-pullall-not-removing-items

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be one of two places:

First your update has a syntax issue:

```
db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId(".....")}, 
     { $pullAll : 
         { 'notifications' : [{'type' : type}, {'id': id}]
         } 
     }
)
```

should be:

```
db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId(".....")}, 
     { $pullAll : 
         { 'notifications' : [{'type' : type, 'id': id}]
         }  
     }
)
```

Note I removed `}, {` and joined type and id into a single JSON subdocument.

The other issue is your array elements seem to have `id` values which are strings of form "123" - are you sure you are passing a string to your update statement?  String "123" is not equal to integer 123.

Answer (score 0):

To use *$pullAll* you need to match the whole object exactly. Why not just use *$pull*, I'm sure it would suit your needs

Comment: I just tried with `db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId(".....")}, { $pull : { 'notifications' : [{'type' : type}, {'id': id}]} },False,True)` and `db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId(".....")}, { $pull : { 'notifications' : {'type' : type , 'id': id}} },False,True)`  and I have the same result

Comment: Try and $pull using only "type" or only "id", just to see if it works